# Image processing library for D?

Tags: image-processing, d

I started using D a few days ago and I like it a lot. I was wondering... Is there a image processing library for D? Maybe something like opencv? I have searched but no luck...

Comment: +1 for liking D.
lol, jk, good question too. :-)

Answer (score 8):

None that I'm aware of, but one possibility is to simply translate the C header for OpenCV to D.  [D can call any code that exposes a C interface](http://d-programming-language.org/interfaceToC.html), so you can write all your code in D and call OpenCV for backend functionality where necessary, possibly writing D wrappers to make it more convenient.

Answer (score 4):

[Derelict](http://www.dsource.org/projects/derelict) has bindings for DevIL and SDL_image.

Answer (score 0):

[DMagik](http://forum.dlang.org/thread/j8sck9$2d63$1@digitalmars.com) seem to offer the capabilities of [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) for D.